# How do I access a list from the other method?

Tags: c#

I have just started ASP.NET for school and I can't seem to be able to solve this problem. 
In the controller I have created a list with (for now) hard coded entries.
These entries will be shown in a view and in the view you can click on one of the entries. 
What I want to happen is that when you click one of the entries a new view is shown where the details of the contact (so far just phoneNumber & name) are shown.
Does anyone know how I could make this happen?

**Controller:**

```
// GET: 
public ActionResult 
{
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact> { };
contactList.Add(new Contact("John", 10));
contactList.Add(new Contact("Joe", 20));
contactList.Add(new Contact("Jake", 30));

return View(contactList);
}

// GET: Contact/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  Contact contact = contactList.Find(id);
  return View(contact);
 }
```

**Index View:**

```
@using WhatsUp.Models;
@model List<Contact>

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (Contact contact in Model)
{
<a href="../Contact/Details/@contact.phoneNumber"><li>@contact.name @contact.phoneNumber</li></a>
}
</ul>
```

**Contact Details View**

```
@using WhatsUp.Controllers
@using WhatsUp.Models
@model Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Contact Details</h2>
<p>@Model.name</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contact list needs to be outside of your index method.

**Controller**

```
private static List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact> 
{
    new Contact(1, "John", 10),
    new Contact(2, "Joe", 20),
    new Contact(3, "Jake", 30)
};

public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View(contactList);
}

// GET: Contact/Details/5
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  Contact contact = contactList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
  return View(contact);
}
```

You can use the method @Html.ActionLink to create links that link to your details page

**Index**

```
@using WhatsUp.Models;
@model List<Contact>

@{
 ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
<ul>
@foreach (Contact contact in Model)
{
<li>@Html.ActionLink(contact.name + "," + contact.phoneNumber, "Details", new { id = contact.id })</li>
}
</ul>
```

**Detail**

```
@using WhatsUp.Controllers
@using WhatsUp.Models
@model Contact

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Contact Details</h2>
<p>@Model.name</p>
```

Comment: Placing the list outside of the index method worked, thanks! :D

Answer (score 0):

Basically: you can't. This list exists only in method scope.

Instead create property in the controller:

```
List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact> 
{
    new Contact("John", 10),
    new Contact("Joe", 20),
    new Contact("Jake", 30)
};
```

Then modify your Index method:

```
public ActionResult Index
{
    return View(contactList);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here What I Think you should do.

**Create a new View Model For Index**

```
 public class ListModel{
     public List<ListDataaddress { get;  set; }
 }

 public class ListData{

  public int key { get;  set; }
  public string Value { get;  set; }

 }
```

**Controller Action Should be like this :**

```
public ActionResult DestinationList(string searchData){

    ListModel objList= new ListModel();
    ListData obj = new ListData();
    obj.key=1;
    ListData.Value="First Item";
    objList.add(obj);
    return View(objList);
    }
```

**Index View:**

```
@model YOURPROJECT.Models.ListModel

            @foreach (var item in Model.placeInfoList)
          {
            <p  <a href="@Url.Action("ControllerName", "ActionName", new {id = item.key})">item.Value</a></p
          }
```

Details Action :

```
 public ActionResult Details(int id) { 

 // Use Id To bind View for details (New view model you should use.)

 }
```

**Detail View:** You can write based on information you need to show on view